# preg_replace not replacing in a Wordpress plugin

Tags: regex, preg-replace, wordpress

In follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424510/wordpress-widget-plugin-content-based-on-text-of-posts-pages-visible), I want to replace every instance of an ALL-CAPS<sup>*</sup> word with a link of the following format:

```
dictionary.com/browse/<TERM>
```

The `preg_replace` call I am using is this:

```
$content = preg_replace('#[A-Z][A-Z]+#', '<a href="//dictionary.com/browse/$1">$1</a>', $content);
```

Using http://gskinner.com/RegExr, it appears I have my regex correct, and that it *should* be replacing on each find.

Have I done something wrong, either in the `preg_replace` call, or pehaps in the registration of the plugin/filter to the Wordpress API?

---

Full context of the call:

```
function define_filter($content){
  $content = preg_replace('#[A-Z][A-Z]+#', '<a href="//dictionary.com/browse/$1">$1</a>', $content);
}

add_filter('the_content', 'define_filter');
```

<sub><sup>* I'm using the `[A-Z][A-Z]+` syntax to ensure I do not match words like "I" and "A"</sup></sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the function needs to return the result of the replacement:

```
return $content;
```

Also, that regex doesn't look right.  If you want to match a whole word in all caps, it's

```
'#\b[A-Z]+\b#'
```

Also, you want `$0` (the whole match), not `$1` (the first capture group, which your regex doesn't have)

Comment: the `\b` additions helped .. now it's substituting the link, but not appending the `$1` form the match.. any further thoughts perchance?

Comment: I didn't notice that: you want `$0` (the whole match), not `$1` (the first capture group, which your regex doesn't have).