# Matching text between braces in PHP

Tags: php, regex, plugins, wordpress

In direct follow-up to this previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413071/regex-to-get-string-between-curly-braces-i-want-whats-between-the-curly-braces), how can I pull the text (and the braces if possible) out as a match using PHP?

Specifically, I am writing a Wordpress plugin and am looking to reformat all text between two curly braces (a quasi wiki-marking).

I've followed the steps outlined in another previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443207/preg-replace-not-replacing-in-a-wordpress-plugin) I asked, and have the *matching* part working - it's the *match* I need help with.

Example:

```
This is some {{text}} and I want to reformat the items inside the curly braces
```

Desired output:

```
This is some *Text fancified* and I want to reformat the items inside the curly braces
```

What I have (that is *not* working):

```
$content = preg_replace('#\b\{\{`.+`\}\}\b#', "<strong>$0</strong>", $content);
```

If matching **including** the braces is too difficult, I can match using the braces as offsets, and then remove the 'offending' braces afterwards, too, using a more simple text-match function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$content = preg_replace('/{([^{}]*)}/', "<strong>$1</strong>", $content);
```

Comment: you need to change `{something}` , so you put the `{` and `}` , now you need to get whats inside of them with `(.*)` , but you don't need whats inside to be { or } , so you just say (anything except { or }) .. like not [ { or } ] = ^[{|}] . i suck in explaining thing , my boss does not care as long as i get the job done ...

Comment: That `[^{|}]` should be just `[^{}]`.  There's no need for an "or" operator in a character class, so `|` loses its special meaning and just matches `|`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to form a match group using `(` round braces `)`.

```
preg_replace('#\{\{(.+?)\}\}#', "<strong>$1</strong>",
```

Whatever `(.+?)` matches then can be used as `$1` in the replacement string. This way you have the enclosing {{ and }} already out of the way. Also `\b` was redundant.

Comment: I've never heard of parentheses referred to as "round braces." but otherwise, +1

Comment: @warren: Ronans match pattern is more resilient against erroneously mixed braces. While `.+?` is often sufficient to match the shortest possible string, the `[^}]+` negative character class is a more professional idiom. In your case I would consider it interchangable however.