# Extract text between two characters

Tags: php, regex

How can I best trim the following text outside the braces:

```
$myString = "10:0{ 'name':'John', 'age':30, 'car':null }24:0";
```

The text outside of the braces `10:0` and `24:0` may vary.

Comment: That's not a valid string. How is it actually quoted?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, but it looks like a serialized (http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) string.

Comment: @Spingolini: JSON, at least after you do what OP wants to do.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. The numbers at the beginning distracted me for a second.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matching text between braces in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864328/matching-text-between-braces-in-php)

Comment: Yeah well spotted Alex... The quotes between the braces are actually single quotes ' .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just grab what's inside the braces:

```
preg_match('/{[^}]+}/', $myString, $match);
echo $match[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `trim` numbers and colons off with:

```
trim($myString, '0123456789:');
```

https://3v4l.org/vD7XC

... or you could replace everything outside the braces:

```
preg_replace('/.*?(\{.*?\}).*/', '$1', $myString);
```

https://3v4l.org/afN8B